# Regular surfaces with given fundamental forms

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Let $E=G=\cos^2u$, $F=0$, $\displaystyle e=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos 2u}}$, $\displaystyle g=\sqrt{\cos 2u}$ and $f=0$, where $\displaystyle u\in \left(-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$. Does there exist a regular surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with parametrization $\textbf{x}(u, v)$ whose first and second fundamental forms are these six given functions? If yes, find one such parametrization $\textbf{x}$.

I know such a regular surface exists because the six given functions satisfy the Gauss formula and Mainardi-Codazzi equations. For example, the Gauss curvature is
$$ K=\frac{eg-f^2}{EG-F^2}=\frac{1}{\cos ^4u}$$ which is also given by the Gauss formula
$$-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{EG}}\left(\left(\frac{E_v}{\sqrt{EG}}\right)_v+\left(\frac{G_u}{\sqrt{EG}}\right)_u\right)=-\frac{1}{2\cos ^ 2u}\cdot\frac{d}{du}\frac{-2\cos u\sin u}{\cos^2u}=\frac{1}{\cos^4u}.$$ How can we find a parametrization $\textbf{x}$ of such a regular surface?

Comment: I'd try the following in order: 1. Do we know of a surface with these data (first and second FFs)? 2. Look for a surface of rotation with these data, taking $v$ to be the angle of rotation; the metric is Clairaut ($E$ and $G$ functions of $u$ alone, $F = 0$) so such a parametrization may exist. (Here, such a parametrization does exist.) If 2. fails, the Gauss and Mainardi-Codazzi PDEs are solvable in principle, but doing so may entail tracing the proof of the fundamental theorem of surfaces.